# Is $\det(I+B) \le \det(I+A)$ if $0 \preceq B \preceq A$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Is the following inequality true
\begin{align}
\det(I+B) \le \det(I+A)
\end{align}
where  $0 \preceq B \preceq A$.  The notation $B\preceq A$ means that $A-B$ is positive semi-definite matrix.

Comment: Hint: If $C \preceq D$, then $\det(C) \leq \det(D)$.

Comment: @fourierwho Ok. Then it is trivial.  I thought that the above was not true.

Comment: This MO question is relevant https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65424/determinant-of-sum-of-positive-definite-matrices

Comment: @Lisa I know this post is kind of old, but why is it trivial the inequality is not true?